# Lazy loading of images for website to load faster

Tags: javascript, image-loading

i want that before the actual image gets loaded a spinner should be shown so that my website can load faster

```css
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        var allimages= document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (var i=0; i<allimages.length; i++) {
            if (allimages[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
                allimages[i].setAttribute('src', allimages[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
            }
        }
    }, false)
```

```html
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/400/600" data-src="images/banguet-hall-location-icon.png" class="secEightImg" />
    <img src="http://www.jettools.com/images/animated_spinner.gif" data-src="images/banguet-hall-location-icon.png" class="secEightImg" />

    <script>

    </script>
```

the problem is the actual image is shown two times and instead of spinner a broken image (which is shown when no image is found) is shown first
please help

Comment: Cause you included *two* images, *two* images will show up??

Comment: for every image you attach an onLoad event. At the same time you show your loading for every image. When image is load, you remove the loading of this spefic image

Comment: Check out jQuery extension library unveil.  http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/

Comment: Or bLazy if you don't use jQuery. https://github.com/dinbror/blazy

Comment: Did any answer mentioned below or in comments to your question solve your issue?

Comment: No i tried another method of echo.js with min.js file and finally it worked

Answer (score 3):

If you want a spinner per image, just add the spinner URL as the initial `src` attribute for all of them:

```
<img src="spinner.gif" data-src="actual-image.png" />
```

Then, once the page loads, change all those `src` for the real URL (`data-src`) and listen for the load and error events on each image.

For each of them, add a `.loaded` class or `.error` class to the images and style them as you want. For example, you could hide the ones that could not be loaded, show a custom "error" image (using `background-image`) or style them as you wish, like in this example:

```js
function imageLoaded(e) {
  updateImage(e.target, 'loaded');
}

function imageError(e) {
  updateImage(e.target, 'error');
}

function updateImage(img, classname) {
  // Add the right class:
  img.classList.add(classname);
  
  // Remove the data-src attribute:
  img.removeAttribute('data-src');
  
  // Remove both listeners:
  img.removeEventListener('load', imageLoaded);
  img.removeEventListener('error', imageError);
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('img')).forEach(img => {
    const src = img.getAttribute('data-src');

    if (src) {
      // Listen for both events:
      img.addEventListener('load', imageLoaded);
      img.addEventListener('error', imageError);
      
      // Just to simulate a slow network:
      setTimeout(() => {
        img.setAttribute('src', src);
      }, 2000 + Math.random() * 2000);
    }
  });
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.images {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.margin-fix {
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 16px;
}

img {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 64px;
}

img.loaded {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

img.error {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  
  /* You could add a custom "error" image here using background-image */
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img
    src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvfGz.gif"
    data-src="https://d39a3h63xew422.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/20145029/driven-by-design-the-incomparable-lancia-stratos-1476934711918-1000x573.jpg" />

  <img
    src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvfGz.gif"
    data-src="https://car-images.bauersecure.com/pagefiles/76591/1752x1168/ford_racing_puma_01.jpg?mode=max&quality=90&scale=down" />

  <img
    src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvfGz.gif"
    data-src="http://doesntexist.com/image.jpg" />
    
  <span class="margin-fix"></span>
</div>
```

The problem is that the spinner image you use initially might take some time to load.

One solution would be to use a data URI, so instead of:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvfGz.gif" data-src="actual-image.png" />
```

You would have:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,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" data-src="actual-image.png" />
```

As you can see, your HTML document will grow fast using this approach, which is a problem.

A better approach might be to use CSS to add the spinner so that you only include the data URI once. To do that, you need to add an empty `src` attribute to your images initially anyway:

```
<img src data-src="actual-image.png" />
```

Or:

```
<img src="" data-src="actual-image.png" />
```

**If you don't put it, the image will have an annoying gray border you can't get rid of until you add a `src` attribute.**

```js
function imageLoaded(e) {
  updateImage(e.target, 'loaded');
}

function imageError(e) {
  updateImage(e.target, 'error');
}

function updateImage(img, classname) {
  // Add the right class:
  img.classList.add(classname);
  
  // Remove the data-src attribute:
  img.removeAttribute('data-src');
  
  // Remove both listeners:
  img.removeEventListener('load', imageLoaded);
  img.removeEventListener('error', imageError);
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('img')).forEach(img => {
    const src = img.getAttribute('data-src');

    if (src) {
      // Listen for both events:
      img.addEventListener('load', imageLoaded);
      img.addEventListener('error', imageError);
      
      // Just to simulate a slow network:
      setTimeout(() => {
        img.setAttribute('src', src);
      }, 2000 + Math.random() * 2000);
    }
  });
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.images {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.margin-fix {
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 16px;
}

img {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 64px;
  background-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,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");
}

img.loaded {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

img.error {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  
  /* You could add a custom "error" image here using background-image */
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img
    src
    data-src="https://d39a3h63xew422.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/20145029/driven-by-design-the-incomparable-lancia-stratos-1476934711918-1000x573.jpg" />

  <img
    src
    data-src="https://car-images.bauersecure.com/pagefiles/76591/1752x1168/ford_racing_puma_01.jpg?mode=max&quality=90&scale=down" />

  <img
    src
    data-src="http://doesntexist.com/image.jpg" />
    
  <span class="margin-fix"></span>
</div>
```

Other approaches might be to just hide the images initially with `display: none` for example, in which case you might want a wrapper around them to show something like an empty box to indicate the users that something will be shown in there, or even a spinner made with other elements if you want/need to get fancy.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is something like:

```js
$(".sly-main-slider div img").attr('src', "#");
$(".sly-main-slider").addClass("loading");
$(".sly-main-slider div").hide();

$(".sly-main-slider div img").load(function() {
  $(".sly-main-slider div").show();
  $(".sly-main-slider").removeClass("loading");
}).attr('src', "https://loremflickr.com/400/600");
```

```css
.loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  z-index: 2000;
  background: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-nfXo9GWbDtM/VOn0vr4yLMI/AAAAAAAABCA/dDNgd7_QCFo/s1600/block-loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}

.loading:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 40px;
  content: 'Loading...';
}

body {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='sly-main-slider'>
  <div>
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/400/600" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```